# Run script after Debian installation is complete

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, bash, installation

I am using **preseed** to auto install debian.
I want to be able to run a script called "run.sh" at the end of the Debian installation:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /root/example.txt
```

I have tried several models that I have found by google (I add these commands to preseed.cfg):

`d-i late_command string cp -a /cdrom/preseed/run.sh /target/root; chmod 777 /root/run.sh; /root/run.sh;`

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
  in-target cp run.sh /root/ && in-target chmod 755 /root/run.sh \
  cd /target; \
  chmod +x ./run.sh; \
  chroot ./ ./run.sh;
```

I have tried everything I have seen and it has occurred to me, on none of the occasions have I been successful. The most I have achieved is a red screen with an error that the file "run.sh" is corrupt

[I just saw a similar question from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798376/running-a-script-just-before-installation-of-debian-finishes-using-preseed)

Comment: you should run this script by /path/to/bash /path/to/script IMHO

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have managed to solve the problem (I have reused the answer from the other forum, but it is equally valid)

Comment: and to be honestly, it is that what i told,. use bash and the script with the native path to run it :-)

Comment: In debian it is understood that the path is `/cdrom/` when the manual does not say that, in the examples it says that it is `/hd-media/`. And the `in-target /bin/bash` is also an intuitive thing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on the fact that you use a USB to install the OS, and that you will have in the root of the USB a folder called `files` where you will have the file `preseed.cfg` and an executable called `run.sh`.

This command will copy the file `run.sh` to the root of the user **root** and there it will execute the script.

`d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/files/run.sh /target/root/; chmod +x /target/root/run.sh; in-target /bin/bash /root/run.sh`

After this you can use `rm` to delete the file. You can also run the script directly from the USB (without copying it), but after some tests I have verified that it can induce human errors